# Using R to create a new variables based on the counts of categorical variables

Tags: r

I have a dataset that contains an identifier variable (`census_tract_number`) and a categorical variable (`action_taken_name`) that contains five categories. I am trying to figure out how to create a new data frame that will break each category into a variable and show the frequency for each of these categories by `census_tract_number`. I have figured out how to create a frequency variable with count but I want each category to be an individual variable with the counts underneath.

[image: Screenshot of dataset]

Comment: Pictures of data are not helpful. It's easiest to help you if you provide a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the desired output for that input. That was possible solutions can be tested and verified.

Comment: you have clearly not researched well. this is a very basic question and can be answered simply by googling "long to wide data in R"

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(census_tract_number=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                 action_take_name=c('a','b','c','d','a','b','e','c','f'),
                 freq=c(2,2,4,5,28,20,5,40,23))

results <- df %>% spread(action_take_name,freq,fill=0)

results 
  census_tract_number  a  b  c d e  f
1                   1  2  2  4 0 0  0
2                   2 28 20 40 5 5 23
```